# Documentation on email templates

Tags: civievent, message-templates

I'd like to customize the event registration email. When looking at the template, I see things like

```
{capture assign=headerStyle}
{capture assign=labelStyle }
```

I haven't been able to find information about what these lines do. I'm going to guess its adding generated markup. Could someone provide some guidance?

Or, if anyone could tell me where headerStyle and labelStyle is configured, maybe I could figure it out by looking at that.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The answer:

These lines allow CiviCRM tokens to be available to Smarty functions. The headerStyle value is contained within the `{capture}` item.

Documentation found here:

- [CiviCRM Wiki: Smarty in email templates](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Smarty+in+mail+templates)
- [Smarty docs: `{capture}` tag](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.capture.tpl)

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if it's worth mentioning that you can use smarty comments like {* this *}. That way when you research you can update the templates with your findings.